# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray for MapBox

Tags: java, json

```
2020-02-04 13:35:32.521 32631-32752/com.box.rad100 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":1,"company":null,"store_desc":"","store_name":"Позиция ЗРК","category_id":2,"latitude":"59.8713584","longitude":"29.8725824","telephone":"Нулевая","keywords":"Нулевое","photo_url":"http:\/\/trikeenan.com\/assets\/starbucks-after-front2.jpg"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
2020-02-04 13:35:32.521 32631-32752/com.box.rad100 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
```

Please tell me what is my mistake.
I do not understand English well, so please explain how stupid, thank you very much.
My **data.json**

```
{
"id":1,
"store_name":"\u041f\u043e\u0437\u0438\u0446\u0438\u044f \u0417\u0420\u041a",
"category_id":2,
"latitude":"59.8713584",
"longitude":"29.8725824"
}
```

And my code

```
public String getJSONFromAssets(Context context) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputData = context.getAssets().open("data.json");
            Log.e("100rad", ":"+inputData);
            int size = inputData.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputData.read(buffer);
            inputData.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
    private class AsyncTaskGetMareker extends AsyncTask<String , String, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stationsJsonString = getJSONFromAssets(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                JSONArray stationsJsonArray = new JSONArray(stationsJsonString);
                return stationsJsonArray;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //This will only happen if an exception is thrown above:
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (JSONArray result){
            if (result !=null){
                for (int i =0; i <result.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject= null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject= result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name=jsonObject.getString("store_name");
                        String lat=jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                        String lang=jsonObject.getString("longitude");

                        drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),
                                Double.parseDouble(lang)), name);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to read a json file and load data from it onto a card, can anyone explain how to do this in my json example?
I use mapbox service for this purpose

[My json screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJwQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are trying to retrieve is a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`, try something like follow :

```
 private class AsyncTaskGetMareker extends AsyncTask<String , String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stationsJsonString = getJSONFromAssets(LoginActivity.this);
            try {
                JSONObject stationsJsonArray = new JSONObject(stationsJsonString);
                return stationsJsonArray;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //This will only happen if an exception is thrown above:
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject result){
            if (result !=null){
                for (int i =0; i <result.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject= null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject= result;
                        String name=jsonObject.getString("store_name");
                        String lat=jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                        String lang=jsonObject.getString("longitude");

                        drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),
                                Double.parseDouble(lang)), name);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's work,but I can’t understand why I only see the first value and does not see the following array objects

Comment: @UrbanSide In your data.json you have a `JSONObject` and not a `JSONArray`, where the `JSONArray` would come from?

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJwQ.png this my json file screen.
I can’t understand if I need [ ] brackets

Comment: @UrbanSide Where this JSON file is stored?

Comment: in assets folder app\src\main\assets\data.json

Comment: @UrbanSide check that you are reading from the correct file, seems the file you are using now contains only a `JSONObject` and not a `JSONArray`

Comment: How i can define it, I can not understand ...Sorry I'm so dumb

Comment: I use my code from post,and add [] to start and end file.And all work